# Do I want to get the path of a flv file in the code of a page?

Tags: javascript, html, flv, flvplayer

I want to get the path of a video that is compressed in flv. and to download it. Is this possible ?

Here is my video:

url: http://weddingbridemovie.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you're looking for is: http://weddingbridemovie.com/weddingBride.flv

You can use [DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) if you use chrome in the future to find the content you're looking for. Just switch to the network tab and refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using chrome, you can open up the dev tools window (F12) switch to the *network* tab. Refresh the page and you should see the specific file you are looking for. You can open it in a new tab (by right clicking) and download/save it then.

[image]

Comment: thanks broo, I 'm still learning

Answer (score 0):

You can add the chrome extension called '[Video Downloader professional](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-downloader-professi/elicpjhcidhpjomhibiffojpinpmmpil)' that is found in chrome web store. It detects flash videos on any webpage that has flash on it and enables you to download nearly any flash videos such as mp4, flv, etc.